# unable to find the /etc/default/docker with latest docker 17.03.0-ce

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have installed latest docker version  17.03.0-ce in centos 7 and please find the docker version details below,

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:10:07 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I need to do an multi-host networking using swarm and i was following this link [Lab 06: Docker Networking](https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/blob/94fd5f3e9372a8f58ca7b25f3232305731f7cd36/06-networking.md)

They have mentioned to edit **/etc/default/docker** file to comment out **DOCKER_OPTS** value. But i couldnt see any file in my host machine. Where could i find this file to change the value of DOCKER_OPTS

Answer (score 0):

The guide is for debian based systems that use `/etc/default` in Redhat based systems use:

```
/etc/sysconfig
```

in your case:

```
/etc/sysconfig/docker
```

You can edit the systemd unit file directly for your purpose, but its not recommended.

Comment: thanks @Farhad, i achieved this using systemd drop-in file and it worked. [https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/]